# Apps list on Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, 3.1-honeycomb

On the Galaxy Tab 10.1, is there a way to see a list (not grid) of all apps, or to search for an app by typing other than via the main Google search widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a list of all apps in `Settings -> Apps` (or `Applications`) and then select the `All` tab to see factory-installed apps in addition to downloaded apps.